# call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

Tags: android

I use the android "Motorola Xoom". when i play video in WebView appears sound, but the picture is not visible, but when I fullscreen video runs fine. Whereas in other devices such as the samsung runs without problems,
I get the message across logChat:

```
12-06 19:01:47.120: ERROR/libEGL(3959): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)
```

This is my WebView settings:

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.web_view);
 mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings ();
 mWebSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled (true);
 mWebSettings.setPluginsEnabled (true);
 mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls (true);
 mWebSettings.setUserAgentString (HttpDefault.HEADER_USER_AGENT_VALUE);
 mWebSettings.setCacheMode (WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
 if (channel.equals (Const.CHANNEL_1)) {
     mWebView.loadUrl (url1);

 } else if (channel.equals (Const.CHANNEL_2)) {
     mWebView.loadUrl (url2);
 }
```

This bug or is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: This question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3383797/1048722